# blackberry or android

Tags: android, blackberry

I am a blackberry developer for the past 1 year.I now want to switch over to android.Can anyone tell me the merits and demerits of it with respective to future scope.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Blackberry is proprietary to a single vendor--consider being an expert in Blackberry development in 5 years will possibly be akin to being a Palm developer now.

Since Android is open source I can't see it going any way but up.  It should consume the market.  Making this kind of firmware is EXTREMELY pricy--and that price has to be paid for each and every tiny device a vendor wants to create.

Android is opening up a vast market for small device creators to create something that's actually useful, versatile and a fraction of the price.  It's set to be in every single device in the future.

Honestly I wouldn't even bet my career on the iPhone--the whole single-vendor thing is just too iffy.

Comment: Bill K is right. I hate to be negative, but look at the strategy RIM is taking with its own tablet. From [a blog post about the "App Ecosystem"](http://blogs.blackberry.com/2011/04/blackberry-playbook-android/) (emphasis mine): _The application player for supported Android apps will be available this summer, **followed soon after** by the application player for supported BlackBerry JDE apps._  This means Android Devs get to run their apps on the playbook before BB **Java** Devs. That said, I really like WebWorks and you can't be more cross platform than using HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile development is mobile development.  You stand to diversify yourself more by saying that you've done both.  Your opinion will be more valued knowing that you've had experience on both platforms.  No one can predict the future of how long Android will continue to eat up the market share or what lies in store for BlackBerry, but increasing your skill set is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is

go to android. because android is developing well. if you go to android means you will learn new things and now you have the experience in both android and black berry.
now a days android developing more than the iphone.

Comment: Thank you Aravindha for your valuable suggestion.But if i move to android,will the 1 yr experience of blackberry be counted say after 3 years.I mean is it better to have knowledge on different mobile platforms,or its better to make expertise in one particular mobile platform?

Comment: for me having knowledge of different mobile platform is good..

Comment: I personally would look more for java and OO experience than mobile experience since the Android platform is extremely OO. Of course I would have this opinion since right now I'm trying to leverage my java experience to get myself an Android job with no mobile dev. background.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Android is Evolving Faster... Also Blackberry experience is an added advantage to android. If you use Eclipse for Blackberry, then your migration is simple. I was a Java Developer, Now i'm working in Android. Initially the path was difficult. Now i'm happy with the path i had chosen. I already have a couple of apps in the market that have good revenue. Also according to many predictions, android will overtake iPhone in Mid 2012... Also both platform uses java as primary development language. This helps you better. In fact u used j2ME in Blackberry right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is simple. Android is the way to go.

Android's biggest problem is also one of it's biggest strengths: diversity of device manufacturers customizing the OS as they please. But Google is looking to fix that, as far as I can tell.

Also, if if you consider BlackBerry announced that the BlackBerry PlayBook will be running Android applications, you shouldn't even think about it anymore.

Hope you found this useful.

Happy developing!